# How do you add files to a jar using Netbeans 6.5?

Tags: java, netbeans6.5

I am working on a Java project using Netbeans for the first time.  I would like to use Netbeans 6.5 to create a jar including about 50 text files.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to locate the project directory on your drive. And then put all your 50 text files into **src** folder. Go back to Netbeans. You should see your text files under your source package by now. Then **Build** the project. Your newly created JAR should be in your project directory's **dist** folder.

**EDIT:** Here is example source code which reads from text file in "default" package. The file name is "hello.txt".

```
package testtextfile;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream s = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hello.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\Z"); // read to the end of file. all at one.
        String contents = sc.next();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(contents));
    }

}
```

Comment: @AdeelAnsari Because he will probably want to read the text files from within JAR :)

Comment: I used this method and it works only with Netbeans, if I build the jar and run the program, it fails to load the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with ant, ant can do this, and Netbeans can run an ant script.

Comment: You could improve this answer by actually giving some Ant code.