# Include files in a java archive

Tags: java, netbeans, resources

I mainly followed this thread:
[How do you add files to a jar using Netbeans 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435971/how-do-you-add-files-to-a-jar-using-netbeans-6-5)
I have a class named Card then needs to load a file and return the name of the InputStream.
This is the code to obtain the input:

```
public String getFilename()
{
    String result= "" + seed + "-" + value + ".png";
    return result;
}
public InputStream getInputStream()
{
    InputStream result;
    result= Card.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFilename());
    return result;
}
```

The filename is correct, all the files are in the src folder of the project.
If I try to run it with Netbeans 7.2 it works.But if I build the project and move the jar from it's original position, run it, it doesn't work anymore.It doesn't load the files(result is null).
What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move all the files into their own package "resources".

```
String result= "/resources/" + seed + "-" + value + ".png";
```

(This may not fix the problem but it is the recommended solution from various sites when handling resources. I know that this does work for eclipse IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result= Card.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+getFilename());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it didn't find a library, I had to move all the dist folder in order to make it work.